# Is it possible to know what the datatype is in an inputstream?

Tags: java

In the case of a client - server relationship is it possible to know the inputstream's entry data types?

For example if the client output writes byte 2 and string "hey" how can I know server sided that the first entry was a byte and the second one was a string?

Comment: you don't unless you have mutual understanding or delimeters.

Comment: You could also consider a ObjectOutputStream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you wrote (or coordinated with whomever wrote) the client and you know the order in which the client is going to communicate its' message(s) (this is usually known as the [protocol](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protocol)). Some systems include document oriented messaging (JSON or XML) and/or various other protocols like IIOP, RPC, DCOM, SOAP and ReST.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's a byte-stream. All you know is bytes. You don't know whether the next byte is one octet in the protocol, the first part of two, or four, or eight, or part of a longer string.

If the *protocol* is *tagged*, it's a different story, but then if you know the protocol you don't have to ask the question.